# how to add a pre made div using javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that looks like this

[image]
I want it like that every time the save note is pressed a new card with updated title and description appears on the right.

This is the html code I wrote

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 rightLine">
            <h1 class="bottomLine">Note List</h1>
            <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
            <div id ="cards"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1 class="bottomLine">Note</h1>
            <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
            <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4 bottomLine">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="15" placeholder="Enter descirption here"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="removenote" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove Note</button>
                <button type="button" id="savenote" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="x.saveNote()">Save Note</button>
                <button type="button" id="addnote" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="x.addNote()">Add Note</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The card is the one with id=card in the code and that is the thing I want new every-time.

This is the javascript I wrote

```
 class Note {
    constructor(name, description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

class NoteComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.listOfNotes = [];
    }

    saveNote() {
        let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        let description = document.getElementById("description").value;
        let currentNote = new Note(title, description);
        this.listOfNotes.push(currentNote);

        getCardHTML(this.listOfNotes);

        this.listOfNotes.forEach((arrayItem) => {
            console.log('name is ' + arrayItem.name + ' description is ' + arrayItem.description);
        });
    }

    addNote() {
        let title = document.getElementById("title").value = "";
        let description = document.getElementById("description").value = "";
    }


    filterList(noteList, Query) {}
}

/*when the specific note card clicked the title and description places will be populated*/
function showNote(){
    console.log('the onclcik worked fine');
}

function getCardHTML(arr) {
    let divOfCards = document.getElementById('cards');
    while (divOfCards.firstChild) {
        divOfCards.removeChild(divOfCards.firstChild);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let div = document.getElementById("cards");
        let anchor = document.createElement("div");
        anchor.className = "list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start";
        let innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
        innerDiv.className = "d-flex w-100 justify-content-between";
        let divHeading = document.createElement("h5");
        divHeading.className = "mb-1";
        divHeading.innerHTML = arr[i].name;
        let divPara = document.createElement("p");
        divPara.className = "mb-1";
        divPara.innerHTML = arr[i].description;
        //anchor.href = "#";
        anchor.onclick = showNote();

        innerDiv.appendChild(divHeading);
        anchor.appendChild(innerDiv);
        anchor.appendChild(divPara);
        div.appendChild(anchor);
    }
}

let x = new NoteComponent();
```

When a new note is saved it appears on the left side. I don't understand how when that card on the left side is clicked that notes title and description occupies the places on the right.

Comment: You can use the `append` function. Here's a link to the docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I don't understand how do I append the card that I made in the html myself and just append it with the edited title and description

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution IMO would be generate the HTML by looping over the Notes array.

1) This function iterates (using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) over the array and returns HTML using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (what's between the back-ticks):

```
function getCardHTML(arr) {

  // Array.map returns a new array
  return arr.map(({ name, description }) => {

    // In this case the array has a number of elements containing
    // HTML strings
    return `<h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5><p class="card-text">${description}</p>`;

  // which is joined into one HTML string before it's returned
  }).join('');
}
```

2) And you can add it to the card panel like this:

```
const cards = document.querySelector('.card-body');
cards.innerHTML = getCardHTML(listOfNotes);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/68f2qv7a/21/)

**Edit**

In order to solve the next part of the question move all the node selections outside of the functions, and then add an event listener to the cards container.

```js
class Note {
  constructor(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

class NoteComponent {
  constructor() {}
  filterList(noteList, Query) {}
}

const listOfNotes = [];
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const description = document.getElementById('description');

const save = document.getElementById("savenote");
save.addEventListener("click", saveNote, false);

const cards = document.querySelector('.cards');
cards.addEventListener('click', showNote, false);


function getCardHTML(arr) {
  return arr.map(({ name, description }, i) => {
    return `<div data-id="${i}" class="card"><h5>${name}</h5><p>${description}</p></div>`;
  }).join('');
}

function saveNote() {
  let currentNote = new Note(title.value, description.value);
  listOfNotes.push(currentNote);
  cards.innerHTML = getCardHTML(listOfNotes);
}

function showNote(e) {
  const t = e.target;
  const id = t.dataset.id || t.parentNode.dataset.id;
  title.value = listOfNotes[id].name;
  description.value = listOfNotes[id].description;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards"></div>
<div>
  <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" aria-label="Search">
</div>
<div>
  <textarea id="description" rows="15" placeholder="Enter descirption here"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="removenote">Remove Note</button>
  <button type="button" id="savenote">Save Note</button>
  <button type="button" id="addnote">Add Note</button>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think what you have written does work. But I want the cards to be clickable individually. So when clicked on card eg x the respective title and description is shown

Comment: So you want to add a new card to the list on the left, and when a card is clicked the information appears in the form on the right? Because that second part is missing from your question. What's the difference between "add note" and "save note"?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. And I have edited the question. Sorry for confusion

Comment: When addNote is pressed the title and description should be cleared so a new note can be made and then should be able to press save note and then that will appear on the left side

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to run.

Comment: Works for me. Add a note, it will appear at the top, then add another one. Click on the first note and you'll see the form update with its information.

Comment: I removed some of the HTML to make it more legible. Either change your card container to have a `cards` class, or change my code to `cards-body` or whatever your cards container is called.

Comment: using your help I have got to a point that the new note cards are appearing on the left when I save them, but I still don't understand how when I click the card on the left the respective notes title and description occupies the place on right. Can you check the updated code and advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript function called createElement() that allows you to create and assign a HTML element into a variable.
Once the element is created, just append the content to it and then append the element to a HTML element.

For example:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
var div = document.createElement("div");
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
var p = document.createElement("p");
// assign values to elements
h1.textContent = title;
p.textContent = description;
// append elements to div
div.appendChild(h1);
div.appendChild(p);
// append div to body
body.appendChild(div);
```

You can also use createTextNode instead of textContent.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the `listOfNodes` and create `card` and append it to the div. Whenever you click savenote the card will be appeared. Here is the working demo.

```js
class Note{
    constructor(name, description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
      }
}

let listOfNotes = [];

class NoteComponent{
    constructor(){}

    filterList(noteList,Query){}
}

document.getElementById("savenote").addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    let currentNote = new Note(title,description);
    listOfNotes.push(currentNote);
    var newNode = document.getElementById("card");
    listOfNotes.forEach((arrayItem) => {
      console.log(arrayItem.name);
      
      var name = document.createElement("h5");
      var nameText = document.createTextNode(arrayItem.name);
      name.appendChild(nameText);
      
      var description = document.createElement("p");
      var desc = document.createTextNode(arrayItem.description);
      description.appendChild(desc);
      
      var card_body = document.createElement("div");
      card_body.className = "card_body";
      
      card_body.appendChild(name);
      card_body.appendChild(description);
      
      var card = document.createElement("div");
      card.className = "card";
      
      card.appendChild(card_body);
      
      var aTag = document.createElement("a");
      aTag.className="custom-card";
      aTag.setAttribute("id", "card");
      aTag.appendChild(card);
      
      var cardDiv = document.getElementById("card");
      cardDiv.appendChild(aTag);
      
      
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 rightLine">
                <h1 class="bottomLine">Note List</h1>
                <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                </div>
              <div id="card">
                <a href="#" id="card" class="custom-card">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="bottomLine">Note</h1>
                <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" aria-label="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="active-cyan-3 active-cyan-4 mb-4 bottomLine">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="15" placeholder="Enter descirption here"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="removenote" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove Note</button>
                    <button type="button" id="savenote" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save Note</button>
                    <button type="button" id="addnote" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Note</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think what you have written does work. But I want the cards to be clickable individually. So when clicked on card eg x the respective title and description is shown

Answer (score 0):

Replace your anchor template (your "a ...id="card" code) with an unordered list like so:

```
<ul id="cards"></ul>
```

Then utilize DOM's **appendChild()** method: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

So your JS code will be something like this

```
document.getElementById("savenote").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    let currentNote = new Note(title,description);
    let listedCard = document.createElement("LI");
    listOfNotes.push(currentNote);

    listOfNotes.forEach((arrayItem) => {
        console.log('name is ' + arrayItem.name + ' description is ' + arrayItem.description);
    });

    // New code
    let listedCard = document.createElement("LI");
    let cardAnchor = document.createElement("A");
    //...
    listedCard.appendChild(cardAnchor);
    //...
    // The rest of your HTML code for the <a...id="card"> goes here. Little tedious
    // Finally append the listedCard to the UL
    let cardList = document.getElementById("cards");
    cardList.appendChild(listedCard);
});
```